# Split Date and Hour into another column Panda

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, jupyter

I have the column of DateTime which gets combined into one column. However, I would like to separate it into 2 columns of Date, Time.

The time is every fifteen minutes and I need to make it to every hour.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, make sure your datetime column is in datetime format

```
df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['datetime'])
```

You can then easily extract the date and hour from this using:

```
df['Date'] = df['datetime'].dt.date
df['Hour'] = df['datetime'].dt.hour
```